# 同じ属性が設定されている要素に、スタイルシートで別のスタイルを設定するには？

Tags: javascript, html

下記のソースコードは、data-theme属性によりスタイルを切り替えている物です。
時計と、それに色を付けるためのボタンがあるのですが、
"ボタンの背景色＝時計の色"のため`<style>`の[data-theme]の"color"を
"background-color"と同じにしました。
しかし、そうすると今度はボタンの中の文字色も同じになるため、その文字が
消えてしまいます。
ここの矛盾を解決するにはどうしたらいいか、ご教示ください。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>


<style>
[data-theme="black"]{ color: black; background-color:black;}
[data-theme="blue"]{ color: blue; background-color:blue;}
[data-theme="silver"]{ color: silver; background-color:silver;}
[data-theme="white"]{ color: white; background-color:white;}

</style>
</head>

<body id="back" data-theme="silver">

<button onclick="clock.hidden = !clock.hidden; event.target.textContent = clock.hidden ? 'Show' : 'Hide'; match_theme();" data-theme="white">Hide</button>
<br>
<button data-theme="black" onclick="set_theme([back], 'black'); match_theme();">Black</button>
<button data-theme="blue" onclick="set_theme([back], 'blue'); match_theme();">Blue</button>
<button data-theme="silver" onclick="set_theme([back], 'silver'); match_theme();">Silver</button>
<br>

Clock:
<select id="clock_setter" data-theme="blue" autocomplete="off"
onchange="set_theme(clock_parts, get_theme(event));">
  <option data-theme="black">Clock</option>
  <option data-theme="blue" selected> Blue </option>
  <option data-theme="silver"> Silver</option>  
  <option id="clock_setter_none" data-theme="white" hidden>--C--</option>
        </select>
Date:
<select id="date_setter" data-theme="blue" autocomplete="off"
    onchange="set_theme([Od],get_theme(event));">
    <option data-theme="black"> Black </option>
    <option data-theme="blue" selected> Blue </option>
    <option data-theme="silver"> Silver </option>
    </select>
Face:
<select id="face_setter" data-theme="blue" autocomplete="off"
    onchange="set_theme([Of],get_theme(event));">
    <option data-theme="black"> Black </option>
    <option data-theme="blue" selected> Blue </option>
    <option data-theme="silver"> Silver </option>
    </select>
Hours:
<select id="hour_setter" data-theme="blue" autocomplete="off"
    onchange="set_theme([Oh],get_theme(event));">
    <option data-theme="black"> Black </option>
    <option data-theme="blue" selected> Blue </option>
    <option data-theme="silver"> Silver </option>
    </select>
Minutes:
<select id="minute_setter" data-theme="blue" autocomplete="off"
    onchange="set_theme([Om],get_theme(event));">
    <option data-theme="black"> Black </option>
    <option data-theme="blue" selected> Blue </option>
    <option data-theme="silver"> Silver </option>
    </select>
Seconds:
<select id="second_setter" data-theme="blue" autocomplete="off"
    onchange="set_theme([Os],get_theme(event));">
    <option data-theme="black"> Black </option>
    <option data-theme="blue" selected> Blue </option>
    <option data-theme="silver"> Silver </option>
    </select>
</body>

<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" data-theme="blue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="Of" data-theme="blue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="Oh" data-theme="blue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="Om" data-theme="blue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="Os" data-theme="blue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}   

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color
    ClockHeight = 40,
    ClockWidth = 40,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;

var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '...';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '....';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '.....';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.6;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.06,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}

var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = ''
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}

$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Face wrapper
html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}

$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper
html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 

$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)

{

    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';

} 

$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;



// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)

{

    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';

} 

$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;



// Mouse move event handler


function Mouse(evnt) 

{

    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')

    {

        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;

        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;

    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 

{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;

    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();
}());
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
var clock_parts = [Od, Of, Oh, Om, Os];
var clock_part_setters = [date_setter, face_setter, hour_setter, minute_setter, second_setter];

function for_each(array,func){Array.prototype.forEach.call(array,func);}

function get_theme(event){return event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.theme;
}

function select_option(select_elm,theme){select_elm.dataset.theme = theme;
// IE hack
select_elm.className = select_elm.className;
for_each(select_elm.options, function(option_elm){
if(option_elm.dataset.theme == theme){
option_elm.selected = true;
}
});
}

function set_theme(elms,theme){
    for_each(elms, function(elm){
elm.dataset.theme = theme;
        // IE hack
elm.className = elm.className;
});
// update clock_part_setters
for_each(clock_parts,function(part,i){
select_option(clock_part_setters[i],part.dataset.theme);
});
// update clock_setter
var is_same_theme = clock_parts.every(function(part){
return part.dataset.theme == clock_parts[0].dataset.theme;
});
if(is_same_theme){
clock_setter_none.hidden = true;
select_option(clock_setter,clock_parts[0].dataset.theme);
}
else{
clock_setter_none.hidden = false;
select_option(clock_setter,"white");
}
}
function match_theme(){
    var theme_table = {
        // back_theme: "clock_theme",
        black: "silver",
        blue: "black",
        silver: "blue",

    };
    set_theme(clock_parts, theme_table[back.dataset.theme]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `color:` の部分が文字色になると思うので、これを背景色（`background-color:`）とは異なる色に設定してはどうですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば、
「id が "clock" の要素の子孫で "data-theme" 属性の値が "black" の要素」
を選択する CSSセレクタは `#clock [data-theme="black"]` のように書けます。
これを利用して以下のように時計部分の color を特別に指定するとよいでしょう。
（もし、background-color の指定もするならば、このプロパティが子孫に継承されない事も考慮する必要があります）

```css
/* 時計 */
#clock [data-theme="black"] { color: black; }
#clock [data-theme="blue"] { color: blue; }
#clock [data-theme="silver"] { color: silver; }
#clock [data-theme="white"]  { color: white; }

[data-theme="black"]{ color: white; background-color: black; }
[data-theme="blue"]{ color: white; background-color: blue; }
[data-theme="silver"]{ color: black; background-color: silver; }
[data-theme="white"]{ color: black; background-color: white; }
```

もちろん、ボタンの方の color を指定してもいいですし、いろいろやり方はあると思います。

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。やはり、分けなければなりませんでしたか。時計は文字で、background-color が入ると変ですよね。活用させていただきます。